# How do I use Typescript CDK to create an Elasticache user?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, amazon-elasticache, aws-cdk-typescript

I've got a redis engine in AWS - with a series of functions outside of the main scope. But for some reason, part of my code is not being implemented when I run a CDK deploy.

Just for reference, within the main scope, I have a

```
    cache.node.addDependency(userGroup);
```

line that ensures that code defined outside of the main scope is called on.

The variable userGroup refers to a Elasticache.CfnUserGroup that I am trying to create a user for, the code CfnUserGroup is:

```
fetchCacheUserGroup() {
    const ElasticacheUser = this.createCacheUser();

    return new elasticache.CfnUserGroup(this, 'CacheUserGroup', {
      engine: 'redis',
      userGroupId: 'foo',
      userIds: [
        ElasticacheUser
      ],
    });
  }
```

Because the userId field above only accepts string values, I've created an additional function that I've set as type string and I return the username (in this case, redis-user). This function also is used to create the elasticache.CfnUser.

```
  createCacheUser(): string {
    let username = 'redis-user';

    const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'foobar', {
      secretName: '/x/x/x/x/x',
      generateSecretString: {
        secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({ username, password: 'xxx', }),
        generateStringKey: 'password',
        excludeCharacters: ' ^%+~`#$&*()|[]{}:;<>?!\'/@"\\',
      },
    });

    new elasticache.CfnUser(this, 'UserElasticache', {
      accessString: 'access-string',
      engine: 'redis',
      noPasswordRequired: false,
      passwords: [
        secret.secretValueFromJson('password').toString(),
      ],
      userId: username,
      userName: username,
    });
    return username
  };
```

This is where I'm running into my issue. When I run CDK deploy, I get

"User redis-user not found" and it aborts the deployment. How do I fix this issue? It should be deploying completely fine, as the elasticache.CfnUser is created, and a string is returned for the Elasticache.CfnUserGroup, so I do not see what the issue is.